# Call to undefined function lock_acquire with Drush on Drupal 7

Tags: 7, drush

I’m running my local development sites on a Windows machine with Uniserver.  I have them all set up as vhosts.  Most of them are Drupal 7, but a couple are Drupal 6.  I installed Drush for Windows using the Drush Windows Installer.  My problem is that when I navigate to any of my Drupal 7 sites and attempt to clear cache with “drush cc” I get

```
Enter a number to choose which cache to clear.
 [0]  :  Cancel
 [1]  :  drush
 [2]  :  registry
2

Fatal error: Call to undefined function lock_acquire() in G:\UniServer\vhosts\myDrupal7site\includes\bootstrap.inc on line 3198
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.       [error]

Error: Call to undefined function lock_acquire() in
G:\UniServer\vhosts\myDrupal7site\includes\bootstrap.inc, line 3198
```

When I do the same thing with my Drupal 6 sites I get:

```
Enter a number to choose which cache to clear.
 [0]  :  Cancel
 [1]  :  all
 [2]  :  drush
 [3]  :  theme-registry
 [4]  :  menu
 [5]  :  css-js
 [6]  :  block
 [7]  :  module-list
 [8]  :  theme-list
 [9]  :  views
1
'all' cache was cleared in self                                        [success]
```

which is to say no problem.  I’ve checked that lock.inc is there in the `/includes` directory.  Probably related to this is that my Drupal 7 sites hang pretty frequently, while the Drupal 6 sites work fine.  Can anyone give me some direction on dealing with this?

Comment: Related: [Fatal error: Call to undefined function lock_acquire() duplicating drupal site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564017/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-lock-acquire-duplicating-drupal-site)

Comment: Also related: [“drush rr” error](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33456/drush-rr-error)

Comment: Felix, I have the same problem, but the links you provided doesn't solve this problem.